# Substitute for looping using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I want to continuously iterate over an array with delay. In the example below, I used setInterval(). It works ok, but I'm curious is there a better method to achieve this?

---

```
var message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
var print = message.split(" ");


var iterateOverMsg = function(arr) {
    $('p').hide().append(arr[0]).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(2000);
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
        $('p').hide().text(arr[i]).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(2000);
        i++;
        if (i >= arr.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, 5000);
}(print);
```

---

https://jsfiddle.net/Tzaru/94oym3yn/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is looking for optimizations/ improvements and CodeReviews is the correct portal for it.

Comment: Instead of `i++; if (i >= arr.length) { i=0` you can try `i = (i+1)% arr.length`. Also not sure about this `fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(2000)` but should `fadeOut` be in the callback to fadeIn?

Comment: You could use HTML5 Animation and Transition events for this: See 'ontransitionend' and 'onanimationend'

Comment: setInterval is a function that executes a piece of code every certain amount of ms, that's exactly what you want to achieve, why would you change it? you can implement intervals also with setTimeout, but I don't get the point doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve this in a couple of ways. Firstly you can use the modulo operator to 'wrap' the incremental number around the array without needing to detect it exceeding the bounds of the array. Secondly you can use recursion to infinitely loop through the array. Finally, you can use `setTimeout()` to ensure the timing does not get out of sync. Try this:

```js
var print = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet".split(" ");

function iterateOverMsg(arr, i) {
  $('p').hide().text(arr[i % arr.length]).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(2000);
  setTimeout(iterateOverMsg.bind(this, arr, ++i), 5000);
}
iterateOverMsg(print, 0);
```

```css
.dynamicText {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="dynamicText"></p>
```

Comment: Hey, Rory, great refactoring here. Thanks for a great suggestion.